# Trying to get the audio to start playing first

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

**How would I get the audio to start playing here?**

I'm trying to have the audio play first before it's clicked.
How would I do this? I tried different things and couldn't figure it out.
The code after this is how it originally worked.

https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/142/

```
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");
    const hide = (el) => el.classList.add("hide");

    function getButtonContainer(el) {
      while (el.classList.contains("playButton") === false) {
        el = el.parentNode;
      }
      return el;
    }

    function hideAllButtons(button) {
      button.querySelectorAll(".play, .pause, .speaker").forEach(hide);
    }

    function getPlay(button) {
      return button.querySelector(".play");
    }

    function getPause(button) {
      return button.querySelector(".pause");
    }

    function showPlayButton(button) {
      const play = getPlay(button);
      hideAllButtons(button);
      show(play);
      button.classList.remove("active");
    }

    function isPlaying(button) {
      const play = getPlay(button);
      return play.classList.contains("hide");
    }

    function pauseAllButtons() {
      const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".playButton");
      buttons.forEach(function hidePause(button) {
        if (isPlaying(button)) {
          showPlayButton(button);
        }
      });
    }

    function showPauseButton(button) {
      const pause = getPause(button);
      pauseAllButtons();
      hideAllButtons(button);
      show(pause);
    }

    function getAudio() {
      return document.querySelector("audio");
    }

    function playAudio(player, src) {
      player.volume = 1.0;
      if (player.getAttribute("src") !== src) {
        player.setAttribute("src", src);
      }
      player.play();
    }

    function showButton(button, opts) {
      if (opts.playing) {
        showPlayButton(button);
      } else {
        showPauseButton(button);
      }
    }

    function pauseAudio(player) {
      player.pause();
    }

    function manageAudio(player, opts) {
      if (opts.playing) {
        pauseAudio(player);
      } else {
        playAudio(player, opts.src);
      }
    }

    function togglePlayButton(button) {
      const player = getAudio();
      const playing = isPlaying(button);
      showButton(button, {
        playing
      });
      manageAudio(player, {
        src: button.getAttribute("data-audio"),
        playing
      });
    }

    function playButtonClickHandler(evt) {
      const button = getButtonContainer(evt.target);
      togglePlayButton(button);
    }

    function initButton(selector) {
      const wrapper = document.querySelector(selector);
      wrapper.addEventListener("click", playButtonClickHandler);
    }
    initButton(".wrapf");
  }());
```

**It originally worked like this:**

https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/143/

```
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");
    const hide = (el) => el.classList.add("hide");

    function getButtonContainer(el) {
      while (el.classList.contains("playButton") === false) {
        el = el.parentNode;
      }
      return el;
    }

    function hideAllButtons(button) {
      button.querySelectorAll(".play, .pause, .speaker").forEach(hide);
    }

    function getPlay(button) {
      return button.querySelector(".play");
    }

    function getPause(button) {
      return button.querySelector(".pause");
    }

    function showPlayButton(button) {
      const play = getPlay(button);
      hideAllButtons(button);
      show(play);
      button.classList.remove("active");
    }

    function isPlaying(button) {
      const play = getPlay(button);
      return play.classList.contains("hide");
    }

    function pauseAllButtons() {
      const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".playButton");
      buttons.forEach(function hidePause(button) {
        if (isPlaying(button)) {
          showPlayButton(button);
        }
      });
    }

    function showPauseButton(button) {
      const pause = getPause(button);
      pauseAllButtons();
      hideAllButtons(button);
      show(pause);
    }

    function getAudio() {
      return document.querySelector("audio");
    }

    function playAudio(player, src) {
      player.volume = 1.0;
      if (player.getAttribute("src") !== src) {
        player.setAttribute("src", src);
      }
      player.play();
    }

    function showButton(button, opts) {
      if (opts.playing) {
        showPlayButton(button);
      } else {
        showPauseButton(button);
      }
    }

    function pauseAudio(player) {
      player.pause();
    }

    function manageAudio(player, opts) {
      if (opts.playing) {
        pauseAudio(player);
      } else {
        playAudio(player, opts.src);
      }
    }

    function togglePlayButton(button) {
      const player = getAudio();
      const playing = isPlaying(button);
      showButton(button, {
        playing
      });
      manageAudio(player, {
        src: button.getAttribute("data-audio"),
        playing
      });
    }

    function playButtonClickHandler(evt) {
      const button = getButtonContainer(evt.target);
      togglePlayButton(button);
    }

    function initButton(selector) {
      const wrapper = document.querySelector(selector);
      wrapper.addEventListener("click", playButtonClickHandler);
    }
    initButton(".wrapf");
  }());
```

Comment: Just add the attribute `autoplay` to the audio player.

Comment: That won't work. I already tried that.

Comment: Is your audio playing after pressing play?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to get it to play before anything is pressed. This Code is set up differently. https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/142/ Audio should start playing first before it is clicked.

Comment: Maybe this: `window.onload =  player.play()` ?

Comment: I don't know where I would put that to see if it would work: https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/142/

Comment: This is related to how shoutcast works, it is using the http protocol, so by calling it into a `https` context this won't works. You must pass by the url //46.1XX.118.14:15500/listen.pls. Code is okay

Comment: There must be a way to do it, even if I was using a regular mp3 stream. Just because it's shputcast shouldn't make a difference. Maybe someone else would be able to figure it out.

Comment: Unfortunatly, it does. The header sent by shoutcast is of type `text/html`, this is why regular audio js player doesn't play. And the flux is chuncked into small blocks. Looking forward for an answer, this is related to shoutcast,  good luck

Comment: How would I get it to autoplay with the controls showing?  <audio controls autoplay="true"></audio> https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/162/

Comment: The <audio> code you added is pefectly valid and will autoplay any mp3, but this can't works with shoutcast radio. The reason is the following: the shoutcast url is of type `text/html`. This is not valid for the audio player, the header must be `audio/mp3` for example. The reason why you can't import the code on your site is because the url is disallowed to play or is inside a secure `https` context. If so, shoutcast won't works, blocked by browsers because `unsecure context`. Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure? Because autoplay works fine here. <audio controls autoplay src="http://46.105.118.14:15500/;"> </audio> https://jsfiddle.net/1f4xe7v2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listener is based on `click` event, by doing `<svg class="play hide"...` only apply CSS style an no event happen.

you need to rewrite `initButton()` function and check the player state

```
function initButton(selector) {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector(selector);
  wrapper.addEventListener("click", playButtonClickHandler);

  if (isPlaying(wrapper)) {
    manageAudio(getAudio(), {
      src: wrapper.getAttribute("data-audio"),
      playing: false
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with your changes in the code please?

Comment: the change only in `initButton()` but here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pezuLqvo/176/)